# FCM console does not show posted notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android application which uses FCM service. I can send notification from Firebase console and Postman (as it is described [here](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3)) to devices and get them. But when I post a notification from Postman, Firebase console does not show that at all. What causes this problem? How I can solve this?

Note:
[Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49576136) says:

> since late 2018 the Firebase now also reports messages sent through called to the Firebase Cloud Messaging API.

Edit:

I send this raw/JSON as body via Postman:

```
{
 "to": "/topics/Java",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Hello! Body of Your Notification in data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in data",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

Comment: show what you are sending `POSTMAN` and also `message` from postman

Comment: @frankenstein I added that.

Comment: Are you able to receive `notification`  in Device or Not ?

Comment: @frankenstein As I mentioned in my question, yes I can.